# How to show the vector column in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do we retrieve some vector columns in a Spark dataframe?
`.show()` and `.collect()` work for all columns but rawPrediction, probability and prediction after `.fit` and `.transform` of `pyspark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier`?

[image: printSchema]

Error from `pred.select('prediction').show(1)`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-621efd1a0788> in <module>()
----> 1 pred.select('prediction').show(1)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    604 
    605         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 606             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    607         else:
    608             try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1321         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 
   1324         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    188     def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189         try:
--> 190             return f(*a, **kw)
    191         except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1840.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 146.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 146.0 (TID 146) (8fd97f2f2e62 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (ProbabilisticClassificationModel$$Lambda$3511/0x000000084177e840: (struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch!
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.BreezeUtil$.dgemm(BreezeUtil.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.AffineLayerModel.eval(Layer.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.forward(Layer.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.predictRaw(Layer.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predictRaw(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predictRaw(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassificationModel.$anonfun$transform$2(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:121)
    ... 17 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2249)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2863)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2863)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3084)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:327)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (ProbabilisticClassificationModel$$Lambda$3511/0x000000084177e840: (struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch!
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.BreezeUtil$.dgemm(BreezeUtil.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.AffineLayerModel.eval(Layer.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.forward(Layer.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.predictRaw(Layer.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predictRaw(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predictRaw(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassificationModel.$anonfun$transform$2(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:121)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: The error says: `Failed to execute user defined function (ProbabilisticClassificationModel$$Lambda$3511/0x000000084177e840: (struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)`. It seems you should fix your UDF

Comment: Thanks @ZygD but I don't understand what UDF is. I have not defined any function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dimension mismatch error in Spark ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301111/dimension-mismatch-error-in-spark-ml)

Comment: Thanks @blackbishop for the link but I still don't understand how to programmatically ensure the `features` length of the TF-IDF vector to be the same length.